# Cannot upload media with API POST request

Tags: python

I am trying to upload a media with a POST request and it keeps giving an error. This is what I have so far

```
 payload = {
        "templateData": [
            {
                "text": caption_new ,
                "excerpt": excerpt,
                '429279057136': open(f'{media.png}', 'rb')    
            }
        ]
    }
    
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer gstoJiWSw3PdxtQr41oF1ghqv5jyTpcQ"
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

I get the error
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

Comment: Please update your question with error as well.

Comment: Probably the error is in the expression `open(f'{media.png}'`: here you are trying to access the property "png" of the "media" object, which does not exist.

Comment: Week, now you have decided how you want to upload files. You can send it as raw bytes, but in that case the mine type application/json is not valid, or you might want to send it as multipart-form, but in this case you should pass files using the `files` keyword

Comment: Basically you are asking your code to serialise a file descriptor, but it is not serializable